# Log to a different file according to thread

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I have an application with multiple "controllers", and I'd like to have each log to their own file. This is easy enough for their own code, but I'm also using some library code which uses commons logging. Could I somehow get that code to log to the controller-specific file as well?

I was thinking I could somehow do it by thread:

```
class Controller {

 public void action() {
  setCurrentThreadLogFile(myLogFile);
  try {
   Library.stuff();
  } finally {
   restoreCurrentThreadLogFile();
  }
 }

}
```

Currently I'm using commons-logging for my own logging as well, with log4j as backend. But I could change that, if needed, or use a mix (is that's possible within the commons logging framework).

One way I could do this would be to write my own commons logging implementation (possibly a wrapper around log4j), but is there an existing solution?

Comment: Would Aspect oriented programming be an option for you? I think this could solve your problem elegantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to be looking at mapped diagnostic contexts (MDCs).  Commons logging does not support these but Log4J does, so you would have to go directly to Log4J to set this up.  You will probably have to roll your own filter to filter using the MDC and apply to the appenders.

If you willing to change logging implementations then you could use SL4J as the logging facade and Logback as the logging implementation.  Have the controller or some sort of  filter/interceptor add a discriminator value for a key you are going to use to discriminate the controllers with to the [MDC](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#mdc).  Use a [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) to separate the log event into separate files.

Comment: I could possibly change my own library-type code to use SLF4J, but what about code not under my control that uses commons logging?

Comment: SLF4J has support for legacy APIs.  It provides an implementation of commons logging implemented using its API.  You just need to replace the commons logging jar with the jcl-over-slf4j.jar.  See [link](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jcl-over-slf4j).

Comment: I wasn't clear. I know SLF4J has a commons logging adapter, but does that work with MDCs? By that I mean that if I use the library code within a context, will the log output end up in the correct file? (I don't need to be able to edit the MDC from within the library code though).

Comment: Ah, I see.  It is a map stored on a thread local so I would expect it to work fine.

Comment: I've implemented it. Works perfectly and it was a breeze to set up. The only clumsy thing is having to write MDC-setting wrapper code around everything.

Answer (score 1):

A logger per thread? Put the logger in a `ThreadLocal`. If you are using `java.util.logging`, a `Handler` could make this transparent to the caller.

Comment: A ThreadLocal is indeed a tool I'd use if I have to write my own implementation. I don't use java.util.logging however, I couldn't manage to get it configured correctly in Tomcat.